# SFML C++ drawing into RenderWindow pure virtual function runtime failure

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

Im making Label and Button classes. Label basically serves as text which is attached to Button, and Button has the texture of the button and some more stuff.

I wanted to automate things, so you dont have to call each button's draw method separatelly so I made a ButtonManager class, which has a vector and a static draw member function.

The problem is, that the vector contains interface class and not regular one(for future extensions of Button types).

Before I describe problem, lets see code:

File with basic interface for all Buttons:

```
class ButtonManager;

class ButtonBase{
    typedef ButtonManager Manager;
public:
    virtual int getType() = 0;
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow& target) = 0;
};
```

this is very simple one

File with ButtonManager(A bit longer):

```
class ButtonManager{
    typedef ButtonBase* ptr;
    static std::vector<ptr> container;
    inline static ptr& __at(uint index)
    {
        if (index > container.size())    throw std::exception("bad index");
        return container[index];
    }

    static void __push(const ptr& Pointer)    {    container.push_back(Pointer);    }
    static void __pop()    {    container.pop_back();    }
    /*
        Private to hide them from potentional unintended push or pop
    */
public:
    enum{
        DRAW_ALL = -1
    };

    static void draw(sf::RenderWindow& target, uint toDraw = DRAW_ALL)
    {
        std::cout << "container: " << container.size() << "\n";
        if (toDraw == DRAW_ALL)
            for(auto& a : container)
            {
                a->draw(target);
            }
        else
            container.at(toDraw)->draw(target);
    }
    struct ClassImpl{
        inline static ptr& at(uint index)    {    return ButtonManager::__at(index);    }
        inline static void push(const ptr& Pointer)    {    ButtonManager::__push(Pointer);    }
        inline static void pop()    {    ButtonManager::__pop();    }
    };
};

std::vector<ButtonManager::ptr> ButtonManager::container;
```

and finally, a file containg the Button itself:

```
class Button final : public ButtonBase{
    typedef ButtonBase parent;

    mutable Label label;
    mutable sf::Texture texture;
    mutable sf::Sprite buttonImage;
    mutable std::function<void(Button&, ButtonState/* enum class */)> callBack;
public:
    Button() {}

    Button(const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f& size, const std::string& imagePath,\
           sf::IntRect& rect/*unsued*/, std::function<void(Button&, ButtonState)> f_ptr,\
           const Label& _label) : label(_label), callBack(f_ptr)

        //some code
        Manager::ClassImpl::push(this);
    }

    //copy construct
    Button(const Button& b);

    //copy assign
    Button& operator=(const Button& b);

    //move assign
    Button(Button&& b);

    //move construct
    Button& operator=(Button&& b);

    int getType()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    {
        window.draw(buttonImage);
        window.draw(label.getText());
    }
};
```

Note: I tried making ButtonManager::ptr bth ButtonBase* and std::shared_ptr, without success

The problem I have is that when I call ButtonManager::draw(someSFMLWindow), when it tries to call a->draw(target), it will write to console:

R6025
- pure virtual function call

and when I was debugging the code, the error appeared when the first line of Button::draw was called(window.draw(buttonImage)).

Where is the problem? any hints where the problem lies?

Comment: Why not just implement `sf::Drawable::draw` in the ButtonManager class?

Comment: I dont see how would you want to fit it in, because you know, I could just go over the vector and draw manually in main, but I want to automate things, so you just call ButtonManager::draw(window) and it draws all the buttons created edit: I tried, dont think I didnt

Comment: If you implement `sf::Drawable::draw` in ButtonManager, then you can `sf::RenderWindow::draw` the ButtonManager object from wherever. It'll definitely be more uniform with how everything else is drawn in an SFML application.

How did you try doing this and it didn't work? If you just extend `sf::Drawable` from ButtonManager, you shouldn't have any issues

Comment: well, yea I had to remake the class basically, because it was static and now it has 1 global member, but yes it works and wont freak out for now, but the vector wont get filled for some reason, and Im too tired to be bothered by it right now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using static all over the place often reveals bad design choices. Static member variables are essentially globals that break through all "states". I won't go into details why globals should be avoided, but there are enough thread around this topic, so I'm sure you'll find something. I'm also not saying static functions don't have their place in C++, it's just using 'static' to avoid the annoyance of handling objects in an encapsulated way, is not really a solution.

As suggested in the comments, it's really easy to achieve what you want by deriving from an `sf::Drawable`.

```cpp
class Widget : public sf::Drawable {
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const = 0;
}

class Button final : public Widget {
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const {
        target.draw(m_button, states);
    }

    sf::Sprite m_button;
}

class WidgetManager {
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        for(const auto &widget : m_widgets)
            window.draw(widget);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> m_widgets;
}
```

Of course you'll need to add functions for creation and deletion of widgets as well as managing the visibility (what is show infront/behind another widget). You could make static creation factory functions for certain widgets, but other than that, you shouldn't make static functions, but instead think about the design and how to reduce the class dependencies and prevent the "inject-WidgetManager-everywhere" syndrome.

Comment: while it doesn't answer why the pure virtual function call(neither does the comment) but it is very good solution to my problem, and even better than what I've came up to

Comment: Ah right, about the error, it means that somewhere you're trying to call the draw function of the base class, which is pure virtual. Where exactly is hard to say without the code, where the classes are used in.